# static sql for entity in nhibernate log file

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nhibernate to query my db and am seeing various statements in my log files as follow -

static sql for entity
static select for entity
version select
snapshot select

followed by queries using my domain entities.

I believe these are common when building a session factory, but I just wanted to make sure.  Does anyone know what these entries mean?

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just letting you know the sql it's going to use the predictable queries such as get by id etc. They are created when setting up the session factory and then cached for optimization. Very normal.

Comment: Thank you - I figured as much.  I just needed the confirmation.